# Why notch filter can't remove 50 hz frequency?

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, signal-processing

I've implemented a notch filter using matlab function butter [image]

The code is

```
Fs=5000;
Wp = [36/(Fs/2) 71/(Fs/2)];
Ws = [46/(Fs/2) 55/(Fs/2)];
Rp_db=-20*log10(.95);
Rs_db=-20*log10(.05);
[order,wn] = buttord(Wp,Ws,Rp_db,Rs_db);
[B,A]=butter(order,wn,'stop');
```

(At 50hz the module of the filter is 0.004)

Then i use the function filtfilt,and here's the spectral analysis of the original signal and the filtered one. (Nb if i use the filter function i have the same problem)
[image]

[image]

Why does my filter increase the 50 hz frequency?
Do you have any clue?
Thank you

Comment: Your spectrum estimate shows spectral leakage from other strong frequency components present in your input signal. Try multiplying your signal with a [window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) (e.g. Hamming).

Comment: for synthetic data your filter works, so I agree the problem should be the data.